# Adaptivetheme Subtheme usage

Tags: theming

I'm using Adaptivetheme with the pixture_reloaded sub-theme. Keep in mind, it's structured as:

```
Adaptivetheme
  -Adaptivetheme_Subtheme
      -Pixture_Reloaded
```

I'm creating custom edits to template.php to add a node preprocess which creates a custom variable for me, and then editing node.tpl.php to add my variable to the output.

Editing adaptivetheme_subtheme node.tpl.php and adaptivetheme_subtheme node preprocessor gives me the output I want. I understand that the best practice is to edit the sub-theme files...

**In my case is the "sub-theme files" the adaptivetheme_subtheme files or the pixture_reloaded files?**

Pixture_reloaded itself doesn't have a node.tpl.php file, so I've tried copying both the one from adaptivetheme and adaptivetheme_subtheme to the pixture_reloaded directory, but it's like it never reads the file.

EDIT:

> Pixture_reloaded itself doesn't have a node.tpl.php file, so I've
>   tried copying both the one from adaptivetheme and
>   adaptivetheme_subtheme to the pixture_reloaded directory...

I had shutdown my server yesterday, and after bringing it back up, my output was correct.

I had cleared out the cache in the backend of the site... shouldn't that have done it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, `pixture_reloaded` is the sub-theme I want to edit, as that is the last child/sub theme in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible to edit Pixture Reloaded directly, best practices are to make a subtheme of Pixture Reloaded and edit that instead.  If you don't have experience making subthemes, you can use [Footheme](http://drupal.org/project/footheme), which Jeff Burnz (the developer behind Adaptivetheme/Pixture Reloaded) provides for making subthemes of his themes.

Why should you do it this way?  Well, Adaptivetheme is in the process of getting a major update to do responsive design, even in Panels.  Updates to Adaptivetheme Core and Pixture Reloaded will be required.  If you customize Pixture Reloaded directly, to use the new features you will have to update your version of Pixture Reloaded yourself.  If you instead use a subtheme based on footheme, the amount of customization you will have to do to use the new features will be much less.